# export gridview to excel using closed xml with 1 column apart

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, closedxml

I'm exporting gridview to excel using ClosedXML, I want my output to have a one column apart. Like this.
[image]

This is my code for the gridview header part.

```
           for (col = 0; col < headerCount; col++)
            {
                worksheet.Cell(3, current + 1).Value = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[col].Text;

            }
```

Note: My gridview column count is dynamic.

Comment: Where do you define and increment `current`?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 'col' not current, typo error.  I'll try your solution below if its going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (col = 0; col < headerCount; col++)
{
    worksheet.Cell(3, current * 2 + 1).Value = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[col].Text;
}
```

Comment: What if I only want the 4th and succeeding column to have 1 column apart, and the first four column is not?

Comment: You'll have to use normal programming statements, `if`s and such, do output the values to the relevant column.